# Udev rule is not applied

Tags: udev, hdparm

I have a simple udev rule on ubuntu 19.10

```
ACTION=="add|change", KERNEL=="sd[a-z]", ATTR{queue/rotational}=="1", RUN+="/sbin/hdparm -B 127 -S 120 /dev/%k"
```

I have 2 drives which this can be applied to

```
# lsblk -d -o name,rota
NAME    ROTA
loop0      0
loop1      0
loop2      0
loop3      0
sda        1
sdb        1
sdc        0
sdd        1
nvme0n1    0
```

After boot, I check the disks

```
# hdparm -B /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 APM_level      = 127
# hdparm -B /dev/sdd

/dev/sdd:
 APM_level      = 254
#
```

I could not quite figure out why it is not applied to `/dev/sdd`. I am able to execute the command from shell and it works on `/dev/sdd` fine.

Also triggering the rule with:

```
udevadm trigger /dev/sdd
```

executes the command correctly.

Any ideas on how this can be debugged?

PS. `/dev/sdb` does not support APM attributes, can it be that udev stops execution because hdparm fails? In that case how can I skip `/dev/sdb` only?

UPDATE:

After trying it quite a bit and making a shell script to record output of `hdparm` it looked like the output of `hdparm` showed the drives were updated. But when I check the drive settings, they were not applied!

So, now instead I have setup the settings in `/etc/hdparm.conf`

```
/dev/sda {
        apm = 127
        spindown_time = 120
}

/dev/sdb {
        spindown_time = 120
}

/dev/sdd {
        apm = 127
        spindown_time = 120
}
```

and now all the settings are applied

Perhaps not as elegant as using `udev` rule but it works!

Comment: Could you hotplug the disk? Will udev rule work such way?

Comment: It works if I run `udevadm trigger /dev/sdd`

Comment: Try `update-initramfs -u` and reboot

Comment: Why? That makes no sense...

Comment: I guess your rule should be included into initramfs image

Comment: So why it works for /dev/sda if it should be included there but it is not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101129/discussion-between-edo1-and-yurtesen).